# "Vote goes for" vs "Vote goes to"

Tags: prepositions

Do "My vote goes for…" and "My vote goes to…" have different meanings? Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think the first usage could be correct in sentences such as "my vote goes for nothing", meaning "my vote counts for nothing" (or possibly my vote is for sale for very little). "My vote goes to" would, I think, be more normal if you were planning to vote for somebody.

Answer (score 2):

'My vote goes to' is correct.

> My vote goes to Barack Obama

'My vote goes for' is incorrect. You would say something like:

> I'll be voting for Barack Obama

or

> I vote we all go for dinner!

Comment: "vote goes for" seems to be used as well. For example: [68% of Youth Vote Goes for Obama](http://www.dailykos.com/story/2008/11/5/653906/-68-of-Youth-Vote-Goes-for-Obama)

Comment: @Rhodri: It is an unidiomatic usage, certainly, at least for me and evidently for you and others. I don't know what it is that is supposed to make it "incorrect", and it is clearly perfectly comprehensible, despite your pragmatically perverse interpretation.

Answer (score -2):

I think "my vote goes to you" sounds correct.

If you would like to use "go for", you should say something like "I will go for this shirt"

Comment: This is simply a repeat of the existing answers.